# A new Q&A site to discuss ethical issues of the day?

Tags: feature-request

I'm looking for a site that allows people to create and answer questions reguarding legal & ethical issues.   For example, the tape-recording of classrooms...

Although the only Stack Exchange sites that isn't programming are ones like Cooking and English, would it be OK to have something that can have a little bit of controversy?

Comment: "Although the only Stack Exchange sites that isn't programming are ones like Cooking and English" - and Parenting, and Fitness, and Cycling, and Music, and Photography, and many more. Stack Exchange is much *much* wider than programming. Have a look at the [site directory](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: ooo Thanks, I only saw the ones at the bottom of every page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a brand-new Area 51 proposal, [Ethics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32268/ethics), that might suit you.

However, given that the terms "discussion" and "current events" are two big warning signs of an A51 proposal headed nowhere, you might want to look outside of SE.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a site currently on the Stack Exchange network that meets the description you are after.

However, you could propose a site on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), this is where all new Stack Exchange sites come from. Don't forget to search the current proposals first, you should to commit to a site that meets your requirements if it exists rather than proposing another of the same.

Finally, please note that all proposals made on Area 51 need to get a clear definition and a minimum number of supporters to commit to it before it will be considered.

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry for this question being on the wrong site... I wasn't thinking clearly, won't happen again.